# Excel VBA to find non unique values with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am looking for some help trying to create an excel macro. I have a very large sheet that look a bit like this:

```
Account NAME  Address Dealer
68687   Sara  11 Wood 1111
68687   Sara  11 Wood 1111
68687   Sara  11 Wood 1111
12345   Tom   10 Main 7878
12345   Tom   10 Main 7878
54321   Tom   10 Main 7878
10101   John  25 Lake 3232
10101         25 Lake 3232
11111   John  25 Lake 3232
```

---

What I need to do is to highlight all the rows on the sheet where each Dealer has more than one unique value in the Account column, but it must also have some value in the name column. 
So in the above example I would only want to highlight all the rows for dealer 7878.

I am not certain if I should look at loops or arrays, they might take a long time as the sheet is quite large.

Looking for some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you do a pivot-table on a combined Account & Dealer field rather than  VBA?

Comment: if A:A is account and D:D is dealer then use for $A:$D conditional formatting: `=IF(COUNTIFS($D:$D,$D1,$B:$B,"")=0,COUNTIFS($D:$D,$D1,$A:$A,"<>"&$A1))`

Comment: A VBA approach could use a dictionary keyed by the dealer number

Comment: I used Dirk's formula to get something working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

James - Dirk gave you a good answer in his comment. It looks like this ...

[image]

The format formula is also put into Column F, so you can see the results of the calculation.

If you feel you should still have a VBA solution, this gives you a good starting point for how to layout your code ...

1. Ignore rows with empty name
2. Count rows where the dealer is the same as the dealer in the current row, and the account is NOT the same as the account in the current row
3. If the count found in Step 2 is greater than 0, highlight the current row.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try these out.